# Adding domain user to local group when access to active directory no longer exists

Tags: active-directory, permissions, groups

We used to have a domain (`foo`) but the domain controller machine has been dead for a long time.

I am logged into my Windows 10 workstation as `foo\mike` and would like to add `foo\mike` to a local group which already has `foo\Administrator` as a user.

It is not possible to select `foo\mike` as an additional user for this local group because it is "not from a domain listed in the Select Location dialogue box". This of course makes sense.

Is it possible to add this domain user to the local group somehow or is my only option to build a domain controller so the `foo` domain exists again (and even then I do not know if it would work to set up `foo\mike` in the new AD)?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out - yeah setting up a new foo domain controller isn't going to make it work.  need more than just a matching name there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you believe it, I had a brainwave just moments after asking the question.

I opened PowerShell and used `net localgroup foo-group foo\mike /add`.

Hey presto, the domain user is now in the local group.

Comment: I would *highly* recommend to set up a new DC, as local logons with cached domain credentials are limited - everything will be gone soon.

Comment: @bjoster thanks for that. Do you know of any good resources about how to set up a replacement DC (and AD) that will still be able to administer existing domain users when the old DC no longer exists?

Comment: Yes, I do: It is not possible. It's not possible to build a system that is able to manage ressources (like one-way-encrypted passwords and one-way machine accounts) out of ... nothing.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I suspected (and why I have not attempted to recreate the deceased domain).

Comment: If don't do anything, everything will be gone as soon as the local cache is tombstoned. Just a reminder that doing nothing will eventually break your machine.